# How to update the column data such that it will not contain redundant data

Tags: mysql

I have a column with data like **abc,pqr,xyz,abc,mno,abc**

But in my column data should be like **abc,pqr,xyz,mno**, it should not store abc or pqr or xyz or mno more than once.

How can i accomplish this?

PS: There is a chance that when user saves updates data abc or pqr or xyz might be added again.

After user finishes updation, the data in the column should be unique.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a `unique constraint`to the field.

Answer (score 0):

#### Add a unique constraint to the field.

```
ALTER TABLE `foo`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `column` (`column`) USING BTREE;
```

- [See docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

#### Insert data

It may also benefit you, depending on your application, to use a `ON DUPLICATE KEY` within your `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO `foo` (`id`,`column`) VALUES (1, 'bar')
ON DUPLICATE KEY SET `column` = 'baz';
```

- [See docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

#### Fetch unique data

If the above is not possible (for one reason or another), you can select unique records;

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`column`) FROM `foo`;
```

- [See docs](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx)